# How to run Angular 5 asp.net core MVC on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, angular5

I created a basic Angular application on VS 2017 under ASP.NET core 2 and upgraded it to Angular 5. It should run on IE 11, but I notice that it's not working properly on IE11; it works on Chrome. When I read I saw we should do something on `polyfill.ts` but with ASP.NET core I can't see any polyfill file.

Would you tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi chanuri! Did you generate the angular project using angular-cli?

Comment: If you create project with angular-cli then only you can have polyfill.ts.

Comment: What does “it’s not working properly” mean?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan and Aarsh . Thank you for the direction. I solved the problem by creating an angular project using angular cli. And opened it using VS2017 it was created a polyfill for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding polyfills manually generates some error at runtime.
Finally, I was able to solve the issue by creating a dot net core project using Angular CLI. these are the steps.

- open PowerShell as administration mode
- mkdir {projectname} to (create a projectfolder} and goto inside folder
- dotnet new -l to see relevant templates. you should see angular template for 
  core 2.0
- dotnet new angular - this will create a project using the created folder name
- dotnet restore
- npm install
- start {projectname}

then you will open the project using .net and save the solution file. rebuild the solution.
Now you can able to see polyfill.ts and uncomment the IE required imports.

ref https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of VS 2017 Angular Project template there is no pollyfills.ts or main.ts. You can however put the IE 11 import statements below in the file boot.browser.ts which resides in the ClientApp folder:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Make sure to put it at the very top of the page. Also make sure to rebuild the project to fetch the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you not have any polyfills.ts file you can directly include the polyfills into main.ts file then you can run the application in IE 11. Below mentioned polyfills that are need to install from npm and import in your application.

```js
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
 */
import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
 * Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
 */
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Angular CLI dotnet new angular command vs creating a .Net Core 2 app from within Visual Studio (uses JavaScriptServices)  formats the project very differently. For example, when using Angular CLI it includes files such as the .angular-cli.json and the polyfills.ts, whereas the Visual Studio version has a webpack.config.js.

See the below link on how to add IE11 support when generating from within Visual Studio. Basically, you place the polyfills at the top of the boot.browser.ts file. The way I do it though is to place a polyfills.ts file in ClientApp then in the boot.browser.ts file place a "import './polyfills';" at the top.

Also note that the article notes:

> It is essential that you put these imports at the top of your boot file, above the imports for reflect-metadata or zone.js.

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/wiki/Supporting-Internet-Explorer-11-(or-older)